# How do I spend XP in Savage Worlds?

Tags: savage-worlds, experience-points

How do you spend XP in a Savage Worlds game? Can they be spent to improve skills and traits, and/or to gain new edges?

Answer (score 12):

You don't spend XP to gain anything. When you reach certain XP totals (usually multiples of 5) you earn an **advance**, and then you spend the *advance* on new or improved skills, improved traits, new Edges, or buying off Hindrances.

Exactly what you can buy with an advance is spelled out fairly clearly in the different editions' core book (and can be changed by the GM to suit the campaign they're running anyway), so I'm not going to reproduce those details here.